# Capturar el texto de JTextField - no funciona

Tags: java, java-swing, jtextfield

Estoy aprendiendo este maravilloso y complejo lenguaje. Siguiendo un video curso (de youtube) en el cual se encuentra el siguiente ejercicio:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package graficos;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Elio Gabriel Drovandini
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class FocoEvento {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MarcoFoco miMarco = new MarcoFoco();
        miMarco.setVisible(true);
        miMarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}

class MarcoFoco extends JFrame{

    public MarcoFoco(){
        setTitle("Eventos de foco en componentes");
        setLocation(600, 250);
        setSize(750, 350);
        PanelFoco miLamina = new PanelFoco();
        add(miLamina);
    }

}

class PanelFoco extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setLayout(null);
        //Al invalidar el Layout se debe definir posiscion y tamaño para loc compoenntes
        cuadroTexto1 = new JTextField();
        cuadroTexto1.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        add(cuadroTexto1);
        cuadroTexto2 = new JTextField();
        cuadroTexto2.setBounds(120, 50, 150, 20);   
        add(cuadroTexto2);
        EventoFoco focoComponente = new EventoFoco();
        cuadroTexto1.addFocusListener(focoComponente);
    }

    private class EventoFoco implements FocusListener{

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
            System.out.println("Se ha ganado el foco del cuadro de texto 1");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
            String correo = cuadroTexto1.getText();
            boolean check = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < correo.length(); i++){
                if(correo.charAt(i) == '@'){
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            if(check){
                System.out.println("La dirección es válida");
            } else{
                System.out.println("La dirección es inválida");
            }
        }

    }

    JTextField cuadroTexto1;
    JTextField cuadroTexto2;
}
```

Estoy reproduciendo fielmente el ejercicio planteado. Se trata a cerca de los eventos de foco de componentes. El problema puntualmente esta dado en la linea:

```
String correo = cuadroTexto1.getText();
```

dentro del método focusLost. porque no funciona (parece no hacer nada) si en el video se realiza de la misma forma y funciona. Para verificar esto he probado diversas variantes de capturar el texto de un cuadro y el otro en diversos puntos, pero he podido comprobar que efectivamente es esta linea la que aparentemente se esta pasando por alto. Como ultima aclaración uso Netbeans 8.1 con SDK 1.8 y en el curso se usa Eclipse con SDK 1.7. Desde ya gracias a todo por su atención. Saludos cordiales y aguardo su respuesta.-

Comment: Donde declaras la variable `cuadroTexto1`.

Comment: Al final del código, dentro del ámbito de la clase "PanelFoco" y fuera de la clase interna "EventoFoco"

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que **no funciona**? El código lo que hace es controlar si escribes el caracter `@` en el cuadro de texto, imprimiendo un mensaje en la pantalla (**en este caso en la salida de sistema del IDE**). ¿Has probado a escribir en el TextField, mirado luego la ventana `Output` de NetBeans, o sea, dentro del IDE, para verificar que no está imprimiendo nada?

Comment: Si, tal cual he realizado eso, ademas de tratar de capturar el texto y pasarlo al otro cuadro y nada ocurre. En el video curso pasa exactamente los mismo sy si funciona, por que?

Comment: ¿No será que necesitas un evento para el jTextField? private void cuadroTexto1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //capturamos el texto introducido String textoCapturado = cuadroTexto1.getText(); //imprimimos en consola para comprobar que hemos capturado el texto System.out.println(textoCapturado); }

Answer (score 1):

la causa de que getText no funcione, es que el método  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) cada vez que la ventana recibe una acción se vuelve a pintar la lamina, y esto hace que el texto de cuadro de texto vuela a queda vacío, la solución seria crear un constructor para la clase PanelFoco, e incluir todo el código que tiene el metodo paintComponent(Graphics g) excepto super.paintComponent(g);

entonces la clase quedaría así:

```
class PanelFoco extends JPanel{

     public PanelFoco(){

        setLayout(null);
        cuadroTexto1 = new JTextField();
        cuadroTexto1.setBounds(120, 10, 150, 20);
        add(cuadroTexto1);
        cuadroTexto2 = new JTextField();
        cuadroTexto2.setBounds(120, 50, 150, 20);   
        add(cuadroTexto2);
        EventoFoco focoComponente = new EventoFoco();
        cuadroTexto1.addFocusListener(focoComponente);
    }    

    private class EventoFoco implements FocusListener{


        public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
            System.out.println("Se ha ganado el foco del cuadro de texto 1");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
            String correo = cuadroTexto1.getText();
            boolean check = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < correo.length(); i++){
                if(correo.charAt(i) == '@'){
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            if(check){
                System.out.println("La dirección es válida");
            } else{
                System.out.println("La dirección es inválida");
            }
        }

    }

    JTextField cuadroTexto1;
    JTextField cuadroTexto2;
}
```

espero les funcione, Postdata: Leer los comentarios en los vídeo, ya que esta Solución la encontré en ellos.

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo muy bien tu problema pero te puedo decir que  si esta capturando el dato, solo que no lo estas imprimiendo, prueba con este codigo, reemplzanado el metodo focusLost

### @Override

```
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
        String correo = cuadroTexto1.getText();
        boolean check = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < correo.length(); i++){
            if(correo.charAt(i) == '@'){
                check = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("primer cuadro"+cuadroTexto1.getText());
         System.out.println("segundo cuadro"+cuadroTexto2.getText());
        
        if(check){
            System.out.println("La dirección es válida");
        } else{
            System.out.println("La dirección es inválida");
        }
    }
```

Comment: He probado la modificación que comentaste y la salida es:

<code>
Se ha ganado el foco del cuadro de texto 1


La dirección es inválida
</code>

Ya he realizado varias pruebas de este tipo y siempre es lo mismo los println() parecen imprimir solo el retorno de carro

Answer (score 0):

Prueba declarar los campos de la clase "PanelFoco"
antes de los métodos.

osea los cuadros de texto:

```
class PanelFoco extends JPanel{

 JTexField cuadroTexto1;
 JTexField cuadroTexto2;
```

// etc etc etc
...

}